# White fill in organization chart's connector lines

Tags: highcharts

I'm using a Organization chart and I get this white fill with all the connector lines. I've checked all the color in the code and i couldn't find the element that is causing it.
https://jsfiddle.net/y_tddel/jdtoc10q/2/

```
 .
```

I had started with this demo. and the issue can be seen here as well. It becomes clearly visible when 'inverted' is set to false,
https://codepen.io/mushigh/full/gJEZxm

EDIT:
Added an [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0xdma.png) for reference
.

EDIT2: [Node & parent highlight](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5lvop.png)

Comment: Could you explain more precisely what do you have in mind by saying: `I get this white fill with all the connector lines.`? I am not sure if I understood you well. Some image could be useful.

Comment: Hi, @SebastianWędzel. I've added an image of the issue to the original post.

Comment: It seems that the problem is with this CSS config. Do you need to use it? https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/t3fh9sa7/

Comment: Nice! Thank you for fixing the issue. A node and it's parent used to be highlighted on hover (reference image attached in main post). Is there any way to achieve that effect?

Comment: Would you like to achieve this effect? https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/8qj47x5u/

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I was looking for. Thanks again for your time and effort, Sebastian.